# Rebol font size not working

Tags: rebol

For some reason when I run my code - or even the example codes from the Rebol website - the font size of the GUI text do not have an effect. I can write:

```
view layout [ text "This should be big!" font [size: 50] ]
```

or even:

```
view layout [ text "This should also be big!" font-size 50 ]
```

but neither do anything. Peculiarly, however, I can add a color to the text.

Comment: What OS? I assume R2 2.7.8. What if you specify a font name as well? Works here on Win7, both examples.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9.2   running R2 2.7.8
Just tried using a button to change the font size with no effect.
However, changing the font name did work and the size was updated. I'm not sure why this is, but thanks!

Comment: R2 GUI for OS X is...not great. Glad it worked.

Comment: Gregg: its better to write your comment as an answer so Elijah can accept it.

Comment: There does seem to be something *wrong* with default font on OSX.   According to [docs](http://www.rebol.com/docs/view-face-content.html) its `font-sans-serif`.   Explicitly specifying this (or `sans-serif`) still does nothing :(    Like you've found out specifying another font (for eg. `times`) works fine :)